# Find closest 10 cities with MySQL using latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I have searched the Web a lot to find the solution for my problem but I still can't figure it out.

I have a very simple database with id, city name, latitude, longitude and city_info. When someone enters a city page a would like to show the 10 nearby cities.

How can I calculate this with MySQL and return it with PHP?

I have seen a lot of suggestions on this website, however none of these work somehow.

What I tried without success. I do not get any results.

```
<?php
$slatitude = 43.2141341;
$slongitude = 64.4368684;
$miles = 200;

//connect

$query = "SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$slongitude') ) + 
sin( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM cities HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 10";

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$id = $row['id'];
$cityname = $row['cityname'];
$latitude = $row['latitude'];
$longitude = $row['longitude'];

echo "$cityname<br />";

}}

?>`
```

Comment: Do you * definitely* have cities within 200 miles in your database?

Comment: Do you get results without the `HAVING` clause?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: I have definitely cities within 200 miles in my database. I dont get any errors at all.

Comment: For short distances (under 200 miles is short), I suggest using the 'equirectangular projection' rather than the 'law of cosines' for distance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use having because your not grouping by anything. What you need to do is repeat what you did in the select in the where.

```
$query = "SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$slongitude') ) + 
sin( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM cities WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$slongitude') ) + 
sin( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

or you could do something like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM (
  select *, 
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
  cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
  cos( radians( longitude ) - 
  radians('$slongitude') ) + 
  sin( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
  sin( radians( latitude ) ) )) as distance from cities
) WHERE distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Comment: You need to move the `AS distance` in your second query to inside to subquery.

Comment: I believe the query would work as originally written with the `HAVING` clause.  Aliased expressions can be used in `HAVING` clauses without a `GROUP BY` in MySQL, but it is not standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. @Ian Overton, ok I replaced my code with your code. Still I do not get any results...

Comment: are you able to get results with SELECT * FROM (
  select *, 
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
  cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
  cos( radians( longitude ) - 
  radians('$slongitude') ) + 
  sin( radians('$slatitude') ) * 
  sin( radians( latitude ) ) )) as distance from cities
) ?

Comment: I feel like there is an error with your sql. Are you able to echo out what sql is produced and run the sql by hand via your database directly? Please try both my queries without the where, order by and limit. They should be work though.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to a tut how to run a sql by hand?

Comment: I'd recommend installing PHPMyAdmin. It's pretty user friendly

Comment: @Ian Overton thanks. I runned a lot of qsls in PHPmyAdmin. I had to place apostrophes before and after latitude and longitude. Now it does show results but all distances are the same: 3631.06525887798. I am not sure how that is possible. I store the coordinates in float (type). Any idea?

Comment: To be clear..I used your first query. Your second query works as well when I deleted the first "SELECT * FROM" and the WHERE statement. The outcomes stays the same tho, 3631.06525887798

Comment: Ok, I have a working solution. Somehow I found the solution in the ' and the `. Not quite sure what the difference is. Thanks anyone for all suggestions and solutions!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. I'm sorry I was way from my computer for a few days, so I wasn't able to help you. The difference between ' and ` is ` is used in the select to talk about a certain column ie `column1`, `column2` where the ' is used for strings.

Comment: Second example is missing `AS ...` after `FROM (...)` giving `every derived table must have its own alias` error.

Comment: **Tip:** In big databases this method is very slow. You might want to limit it by lat/long, like I did: `"... WHERE Latitude > ".($slatitude-1.5)." AND Latitude < ".($slatitude+1.5)." AND Longitude > ".($slongitude-1.5)." AND Longitude < ".($slongitude+1.5)." ..."` With this method, it become 100 times faster (0.03s) than before (3s)

Answer (score 2):

To improve the speed of your query you could first limit the set of results that you'll do calculations for using something like the sub-select below (note that I also used a different method for calculating the distance - it works for me, ymmv).
In my tests, using the where clause with a tolerance of 1 was over 100 times faster than the query without it.

```
...
$tol = 1; // limits the search to lat/long within 1 from the given values
$query_args = array($lat,$long,$lat-$tol,$lat+$tol,$long-$tol,$long+$tol);
$query = "
  SELECT *,latitude, longitude, 
    SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - %s) , 2 ) 
        + POW( 69.1 * ( %s - longitude ) 
          * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) 
    AS distance FROM zipcodes
      WHERE latitude > %d AND latitude < %d 
      AND longitude > %d AND longitude < %d 
  ORDER BY distance ASC limit 10
";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query I use to get the closest zip codes from a given latitude/longitude set. The table is very simple:

id, zip, lat, lng

This query assumes your center point is using "$slatitude: and :$slongitude". This will return all matches that are within the distance variable "$miles" (i.e. 3, 2.4, 1000). In my script the results are put in to an array and asorted for closest X number of results.

```
$getzip = mysql_query("SELECT zip,((ACOS(SIN(".$slatitude." * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(".$slatitude." * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((".$slongitude." - lng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM zips HAVING distance<='$miles' ORDER BY 'distance' ASC", $link2) or die (mysql_error($link2));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

the far most easy solution would be:

get the coordinates for the city and

```
select ...
order by abs(`Latt`-reqLatt) * abs(`Long`-reqLong)
```

it isn't perfect but you'd be able to sort out what you want from the top 50.

Comment: That would probably work in general, but it doesn't use a projection, so some errors would show up with cities near the edge of the radius and sorting of cities with similar distances.  The "radius" would also be "square".

Comment: This also doesn't offer a way to limit by 200 miles.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PDO for this as mysql_ functions are being deprecated

```
<?php
 //Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);//Change to suit 
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cities HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$slatitude);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$slongitude);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$slatitude);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$miles);
    //Execute query
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount()>0) { 
    // Iterate through the rows
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $cityname = $row['cityname'];
        $latitude = $row['latitude'];
        $longitude = $row['longitude'];
        echo "$cityname<br />";]);
        }
    }
   else{
        echo "No Records";
       }   
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

This [**DEMO**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) uses this query