# Tools for estimating nearby locations without calling external API (i.e Google Maps)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, distance

In my rails application i have some model Location that holds the address and corresponding latitude and longitude.
At the main page, user can search for a location from which he wants to find the nearest places in location table.
I use JavaScript Google API for geocoding on the client side. Since the limit per user is 25000 req/day i guess i do not need to worry about it cause no one will want to search for a location so many times. I use Ajax for sending geocoded latitude and longitude from client to the server.
Now i'm on the sever side and have a reference point and table of locations. But at this moment, i guess i cannot use geocoder gem which use Google API for estimating some nearby locations, cause from the server side there is a limit of 2500 requests per day and i expect to exceed it(don't want to pay either).
What tool can i use to easily return some nearby locations without calling external API? I know that there are other API's but all of them have either limitations or obligations and since it's more like mathematical calculation i can't see the reason to play around with API at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using a relational database, you can use ElasticSearch to index your Locations and search through them using [Geo Distance Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-range-query.html).

Other similar option would be use a Mongo collection and take advantage of the [Mongo's $near operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/).

**Edit:**

There're some questions related to your question which can be useful if you're using MySQL/PostgreSQL:

[Find closest 10 cities with MySQL using latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502360/find-closest-10-cities-with-mysql-using-latitude-and-longitude)

[postgres longitude longitude query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034636/postgres-longitude-longitude-query)